# Enable alternative credentials in TFS on premises

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops, vs-everywhere

Using Visual Studio Team Services you have to enable Alternative Credentials in order to be able to connect to TFS Git Repo. using Eclipse or any other Git Client,

My problem is i want to connect to TFS on-premises Git repo. using Eclipse but there is no way to enable Alternative Credentials, any way to enable Alternative Credentials to be able to do that ? or can i do it other way?

Comment: Why do you want to use alternate credentials?  What's wrong with using your domain credentials?

Comment: Giving the point of using DVC you prolly going to have teams over seas who might not be part of your domain , and a simple way to allow them to connect is to provide them with alternative credentials

Comment: Well, then, no.  Alternate creds are about tying a username/password combination to a TFS identity so that you don't need to auth with a LiveID web browser pop up.  It's not a new identity.  On prem is backed by AD so even if it did allow alternate creds, they would just be a different username/password for that AD identity.

Answer (score 0):

TFS15 now supports Personal Access Tokens and SSH access, so your question isit's not entirely off the mark. There are scenario's where connecting using NTLM or kerberos security is not possible, but as @edward-thomson pointed out, the alternate credential is still linked to a domain account and should not be handed out to 3rd parties.

Instead users will need to be added to Active Directory, or a trust relation (or Federation) needs to be in place so the user is able to join using it's own orgs AD account.

If you're using Git, you could opt to also store the repository on Visual Studio Team Services and push/pull between that and your own TFS server. That way you can give 3rd parties access using their MSA or AAD account, while keeping the main repository secured using AD accounts only. Given the fact that Git is able to transfer data and history with ease, that's not an entirely weird scenario. It fits with the whole Distributed nature of Git quite well.